# realtime-database rule validation is not working when updating data with null

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

When I try to update data in realtime-database with null, `".validate"` in `database.rules.json` seems to be ignored.

I have a `database.rules.json` in the following format (not the exact same way, but this shows what I expect at least).

`database.rules.json`

```js
"data": {
  ".read": "auth != null",
  ".write": "auth != null",
  ".validate": "newData.val() != null"
}
```

When I update realtime-database with

`frontend.js`

```js
import { set } from 'firebase/database';

export class PublishService {
 ...

 setWithData(value) {
  // suppose dbReference has ref to "data"
  // something like ref(this.database, "data")
  set(this.dbReference, value);
 }
}
```

where `value == null`,

I can still update realtime-database with null even though this isn't what I expect.

Is this how realtime-database is supposed to work?
If that's the case, is there any documentation that says that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.validate` rule is not triggered for data deletions. From the documentation on [`.validate` rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#validaterules):

> the validate definitions are ignored when data is deleted (that is, when the new value being written is null).

So you'll want to check for `newData.exists()` in the `.write` rule.